# Storybook unable to run with immutable list

Tags: typescript, next.js, storybook

When trying to run storybook locally, I get an error during compilation.

```
99% end closing watch compilationWARN Force closed preview build
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/amarmesic/colecti/colecti-frontend/apps/web/lib/utils/assetSorting.ts: Missing semicolon. (14:1)

  12 |   "Rarity score",
  13 |   "Most popular",
> 14 | ] as const;
     |  ^
  15 | export const SortDefault = ""
  16 | export type SortOption = typeof OptionsList[number] | typeof SortDefault
  17 |
```

I have tried adding semicolons and changing the code formatting to see if that could help, but to no avail. It seems like a really annoying issue, and storybook does not offer much help besides `missing semicolon`. Removing `as const` gives me another issue related to `flow` syntax not being supported. Storybook says to add `@babel/plugin-syntax-flow`. But this does not help, especially since I am not coding in js rather ts.